# WPF app crashes while reading Serial Data from an Arduino Device

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino board that wirelessly transmits some sensor readings via an Xbee module to a Serial USB  module. 
I have written the following code to read that data:

```
    public partial class Debugger : Page
{
    public static string comportnum;
    public delegate void NoArgDelegate();
    public static SerialPort serialX;
    public Debugger()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comportnum = "";
    }

    private void ActualButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        comportnum = "COM" + comport.Text;

        serialX = new SerialPort(comportnum);
        serialX.BaudRate = 9600;
        try
        {
            serialX.Open();

            serialX.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialX_DataReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Houston, we have a problem.");
            //throw;
        }
    }

    void serialX_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Ping");           
        readingStuff();

    }
    void readingStuff()
    {

        String comdata;
        base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, (NoArgDelegate)delegate
        {
            DebugWindow.Text += "Data";
            comdata = serialX.ReadLine();
            DebugWindow.Text += "\n" + comdata + "\n";
        });
    }

}
```

This works as long as I have that MessageBox.Show("Ping"). Without it, the App freezes/crashes. When it freezes/crashes, there is no runtime error. Even while debugging, Visual Studio continues running, however I am unable to click on any other button the WPF App or even click the close button on the WPF app.

I need to figure out a way to make sure the data is read smoothly without any interruptions without having to use the MessageBox.

Comment: You probably have a threading problem. Try to put your serial-reading in a separate thread, and apply inter-thread-communication to update your GUI if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but try to modify your read method like this:

```
void readingStuff()
{
    String comdata = serialX.ReadLine();
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => DebugWindow.Text += "Data\n" + comdata + "\n" ));
}
```

This will read the data asynchronously (before calling the Dispatcher) and by using `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke` also make sure that updating the UI finishes before reading the next chunk of data (assuming that `SerialPort.DataReceived` isn't called concurrently).